# Java package folder naming conventions

Tags: java, package, naming

This is very entry level question and might have been answered already.
My question is, what is the correct way to name my package folders?
for example, I want to have package named - com.stack.abc
**Option A-** shall I create package folder with name - `com.stack.abc?`
or
**Option B-** shall I create folder structure as shown below?

```
com   
  |_stack   
        |_abc
```

To summarise, I should have only one folder (com.stack.abc) or 2 subfolders under com?

Answer (score 1):

Edit due to main post edited;

You would create 3 different folders. One folder called com, one folder inside com called stack, and one folder inside stack called abc. On some, or most IDEAs, it will look like 1 folder because it looks like com.stack.abc but it's really 3 folders.

Generally you define the source folder (top level of all java files) as

```
src/main/java/
```

Then you define the package that represents your website (if any)

```
com.stack.abc
```

This would resolve to;

```
abc.stack.com
```

The entire directory would look like this;

```java
src/main/java/com/stack/abc
```

This might be a helpful link into [packaging conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

Comment: Aggre, my question is I should create 3 subfolders or just one with dots inside its name. See edited summary of question

Comment: You would create 3 different folders. One folder called com, one folder inside com called stack, and one folder inside stack called abc. On some, or most IDEAs, it will look like 1 folder because it looks like **com.stack.abc** but it's really 3 folders.

Comment: Thanks Jason for your answer. Both approaches will work fine and code will compile with no issues. shall I have 3 subfolders as per some standard(mentioned anywhere?)? . What are the consequences(bad) if I create single folders for hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

To your question, com.stack.abc should be the folder hierarchy structure.

`com
  |-stack
        |-abc`

Comment: You mean option B?

Comment: Right, Option B. In most IDEs like IntelliJ, when you create the package name as com.stack.abc, it automatically creates that folder hierarchy for you.